# VPN not showing computers in network, but can use UNC path

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, network-share

I have recently set up a Windows Server 2008 R2 with Routing and Remote Access for VPN access to our internal network from a remote location. I am able to connect with domain credentials, and group policy updates just fine.

One thing I can't quite figure out is the "network neighborhood" view is not showing internal network computers over VPN. But the share will work if I type in the UNC path i.e. `\\10.1.10.200`, or `\\desktop-1`. I have tried possible solutions such as:

- Making sure my domain controller is the primary PDC emulator.
- Enabling broadcast name resolution is checked within IPv4 settings.
- Enabling Computer Browser service.

What could be causing this? I can use nslookup and resolve all the names of vpn client machines, so what gives?

Comment: Is this a site-to-site VPN or a client-to-site VPN?

Comment: Client-to-Site ... using VPN client built into Windows 7

Comment: Do you really need network browsing?  It sure seems to me that Microsoft has mostly given up on doing anything with that.

Comment: Why do you need to see the computers? I've never understood why people get so hung up on this.

Comment: If they've given up on network browsing, then why include it in the operating system at all? Was more curious than anything as to why the functionality isn't there, even though I can access the computers by typing the paths manually; Seems incomplete to me.

Comment: `why include it in the operating system at all?` - Backward compatibility.  Microsoft rarely removes functionality, but there is a whole bunch of leftover stuff from the past that basically gets ignored, and never updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Network browsing across VPNs has always been problematic in my experience. If I were you I'd use [a WINS server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc784180(WS.10).aspx) to get browsing to work (in an even remotely reliable manner). Other methods may well work, but deploying WINS is pretty straightforward and easy and, in my experience, has done the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following sanity checks:

- ensure all machine have 'Network and Sharing Center > Turn on network discovery' enabled for private network types
- ensure your VPN is classified as a 'Private network', if it is a gateway-less no internet access connection you can force it private as per here: https://superuser.com/questions/1160421/how-do-i-force-windows-10-to-see-a-network-as-private#1160433 and here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/662e5ac6-b0c2-48e6-8a86-a00eaa9c4ba1/change-quotunidentified-networkquot-networ-location-from-public-to-private

  - however this didn't work for me on stupid mess that windows 10 is, if you figure it out please update my answer
- If you are still unable to see computers do following temporary test and disable firewall on each computer and enable network discovery for Public (and 'All Networks' on Windows 10) network types in the 'Network and Sharing Center' options - that's how I realized there is hope